# cannot implicitly convert type "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Book>" to '"int"

Tags: c#, linq, compiler-errors

I have got the following class and collection books that consists of objects of class Book. I have to write a linq-query that selects book written between 1900 and 2000 years

```
class Book
{
    public string Title { set; get; }
    public int Year { set; get; }
} 

var v =  from book in books
         where book.Year > 1900 && book.Year < 2000
         select book;
```

But I got compiler error :

```
error CS0029: cannot implicitly convert type "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Book>" to "int"
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Post the code where you init IEnumerable<Book> ie the books instance

Comment: The code you provided us shows only the class and the Linq query you are doing, but not the actual line you are facing the problem. Could you show more of your code to us?

Comment: Is that your entire code? I don't see where that error would be thrown, as your LINQ query looks correct. Please post the code where you are operating on the `var v` variable.

Answer (score 0):

A list with all your books

```
List<Book> books = new List<Book> {...}
```

Count of the cases you want

```
int counts = books.Count(p => p.Year > 1900 && p.Year< 2000);
```

code is not checked, but I think it should work.

Comment: I think he is looking for the book objects, not just the count

Comment: tbh, the question is so vague, that the only integer that can be coming out of this, based on his description, is counts of books with those conditions. I would post this as a comment instead of an answer if I could

Comment: Still, please don't answer vague questions and don't use answers as a substitute for comments. Vote to close instead.